# Searching button doesn't work when i click

Tags: vb.net

when I type "Sang" in textbox , the table doesn't show the `Judul Buku` with "Sang" word in the table.
[image: This is the picture when I clicked the Search Button]

This is the code in Search button :

```
Private Sub TsSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsSearch.Click
    If TxtKeyword.Text <> "" Then
        TBL_BukuTableAdapter.FillByJudulBuku(UASDataSet.TBL_Buku, TxtKeyword.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

I also add the `Search Button` in the Query..
[image: Picture of Query Code]

Comment: 1. Can you replace the picture of the code with actual code, please

Comment: 2. Please describe what does happen and why it is wrong or doesn't work

Comment: @JayV Sorry bro, I just updated the Description..

Comment: Does it return no rows or all of the rows each time you do a search?

Comment: @JayV it shows all of the rows each time when I click Search Button.

Comment: @JayV okay bro, but when I follow your suggestion, I already removed the @ but I got error, I can not finish the query.. [link][https://i.stack.imgur.com/K576H.png]

Comment: Hi, based on the error message, you have some differences between the database column type and the type of the parameter you are passing in. At a guess, I think your database field is `TEXT` and the parameter is `VARCHAR` - I would change the database to be `VARCHAR(250)` - the 250 represents the maximum length of the data allowed in that column

Comment: @jayv yup I use `text` as  type data  for all my data except primary key is `int`
so I have to change the type data yea?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @jayV great.. It's work. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one too many `@` symbols in your `WHERE` clause

> WHERE (@Judul_buku LIKE '%' + @Judul_buku + '%')

With this statement, you are comparing the parameter with itself, this will always be true, therefore all of the rows in the table will be returned.

You should remove the first `@` symbol to refer to the column and not the parameter, like:

```
WHERE (Judul_buku LIKE '%' + @Judul_buku + '%')
```

Comment: Well spotted! Also, quoting what was meant to be the column name, e.g. `WHERE ([@Judul_buku] LIKE '%' + @Judul_buku + '%')` in T-SQL, would have given an error when trying to execute the query, perhaps making it easier to track down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using BindingSource.Filter rather than loading data on each search/filter. In the screenshot below a contains/like is demonstrated using either a button click or on text change. Also if nothing is in the TextBox the filter is removed.

**Note** The only reason this might not work for you is in the event new records might be added from an external program.

**Full source** can be found in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/tableadapter-basics-vb). There are two form projects in the repository, this is [the one you want](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/tableadapter-basics-vb/tree/master/TableAdapter101). In the repository there is a [script](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/tableadapter-basics-vb/blob/master/script.sql) to create and populate the database.

```
Private Sub LastNameContainsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles LastNameContainsButton.Click

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastNameContainsTextBox.Text) Then
        ContactsBindingSource.Filter = ""
    Else
        ContactsBindingSource.Filter = $"LastName LIKE '%{LastNameContainsTextBox.Text}%'"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub LastNameContainsTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles LastNameContainsTextBox.TextChanged

    ContactsBindingSource.Filter = $"LastName LIKE '%{LastNameContainsTextBox.Text}%'"

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just updated my description about my question, Sorry, I don't really understand, but I add the `Query` in `Button Search`


This is the code


`SELECT id_buku, Judul_buku, Pengarang, Penerbit, Tahun_terbit, Kategori
FROM   TBL_Buku
WHERE (@Judul_buku LIKE '%' + @Judul_buku + '%')`